# PyQT5 media player from playlist

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, media-player, playlist

I've some problems making this work. I wanna use playlist to play audio files. here is my code:

```
playlist = QMediaPlaylist()
url = QUrl.fromLocalFile("/home/user/Downloads/ss.mp3")
playlist.addMedia(QMediaContent(url))


player.setPlaylist(playlist)
player.playlist().setCurrentIndex(0)
player.play()
```

The problem is that when I feed the file as unique media source (player.serMedia()) it works, but when I run the code above, the music doesn't play!

What's the problem here?

Comment: Works fine for me. Maybe you should post a complete, runnable example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I just figured out the problem. I posted an answer for that.

Answer (score 1):

The answer after searching in qt forums is that I didn't provide the player object when creating the playlist.

```
        playlist = QMediaPlaylist(player)
```

Comment: That's not really the reason. In your application, you need to keep a reference to the playlist, because the player does not take ownership of it. If you allow it to go out of scope, python will garbage-collect it. One way to fix this is to give the playlist a parent (any `QObject` will do - it doesn't have to be the player). But you could also just store it a an attribute.

Comment: Ahh, OK, I see what you mean. It's clearer to me now. thanks!

Answer (score -1):

'''how to work it like a playlist add songs to playlist as much as we want and on click automatically play directly from playlist '''
    def open_dialog_box_for_playlist(self):
        filename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()
        path = str(filename[0])
        playlist = QMediaPlaylist(self.media_player)
        url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(path)
        playlist.addMedia(QMediaContent(url))
        song__playlist= str(playlist)
        print("songlist is ",type(song__playlist))
        self.media_player.setPlaylist(playlist)
        self.media_player.playlist().setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.media_player.play()
        print("this is playlist ::::",playlist)

```
    model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
    self.listView.setModel(model)
    for i in song__playlist:
        item = QtGui.QStandardItem(i)
        model.appendRow(item)
```

Comment: Try adding more descriptive comments, and use markdown syntax

Comment: please be more specific in your question.